# While loop menu never ends

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do a menu, it's so easy but I don't understand why never ends my loop, I attach my code:

```
def main():
    menu_bool = False
    while(menu_bool == False):
        print("Menu:\n\t1. Copiar")
        x = input()
        if x == 1:
            print("You have selected option 1.")
            menu_bool = True

# Ejecutamos la función main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Why when I press "1" ask me again to choose an option? I have declared a boolean variable for stop it, `menu_bool = True`, but I don't know why my main function is in loop.

I try it doing a `global variable` but it don't works too. Then this means that my `menu_bool = True` is never done but I don't understand why.

```
menu_bool = False
def main():
    global menu_bool
    while(menu_bool == False):
        print("Menu:\n\t1. Copiar")
        x = input()
        if x == 1:
            print("You have selected option 1.")
            menu_bool = True

# Ejecutamos la función main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: `input` returns a string; you are comparing its return value to an `int`.

Comment: @lurker Yep I'm sure, it's what chepner says. Thank you so much!

Comment: @NEA my bad, I ran it on Python2, which behaves differently in this case (`input` returns the number 1, not the string '1'). In Python3, which you have tagged, it fails for the reason @chepner points out.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, basically you are comparing strings with ints. Also I'd suggest being a bit more pythony with bools, in this case using `not` instead of comparing explicitly via comparison operator.

```
def main():
    menu_bool = False
    while(not menu_bool):
        print("Menu:\n\t1. Copiar")
        x = input()
        if x == '1':
            print("You have selected option 1.")
            menu_bool = True
```

Comment: Could also get rid of the bool entirely by using while(True) and a break statement inside the conditional.